# if field=1 delete else update field=(field-1)

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how to update a field with a negative increment but if the new value is less than 1 delete the row instead?

Is it possible to put and update statement inside an case or if/else block?

Currently I am doing a select statement to get the current value, then evaluating with php and doing a second query:

`if ($row['field']==1) {
    "DELETE from table WHERE k='123'"
  } else {
    "UPDATE table SET field=(field-1) WHERE k='123'"
  }`

just wondering if you could do this in one query?

Comment: Why not do it in two steps? Delete all the rows, then do the update as a separate query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this??????

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (field-1) < 1
UPDATE table SET field = (field-1) WHERE (field-1) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a transaction, to be sure that all of the updates are seen by other users of the database at the same time

```
Begin
Delete from my_table where my_field <= 1
Update my_table set my_field = my_field - 1
Commit
```